# Bouncycastle dependency conflicts

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext, bouncycastle

I have a web application created using spring boot. I have added jasper report, iText and bouncycastle maven dependency. Jasper and iText both contain bouncycastle libraries and now because of this the web application is not working correctly.

Error is: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC. Note that I already added this code: **Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());**

This perfectly works using spring boot embedded tomcat but not when exporting to a war file running on a wildfly server.

Here is how I declare the pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.58</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Upon creating war file, this are the list of libraries included:

- bcmail-jdk14-138
- bcprov-jdk14-138

bcpkix-jdk15on is not being included even I specify it as provided

Answer (score 1):

To quote directly from the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

> **provided**
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

To paraphrase, it uses the .jar marked as "provided" to compile (and test) your software, but when you package it up, it will not be included in the .war: you are expecting the runtime system to provide a (presumably different) version of those classes.

Try removing changing the scope of that dependency to "compile" to see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: While the description of the effects of **provided** are correct, the result of removing it would be a mix of BouncyCastle artifacts with different versions in the class path. This is very likely to not work at all, in particular as between 1.38 and 1.58 there was a major API break in BC.

Comment: Well, the question specifically stated that "bcpkix-jdk15on is not being included even I specify it as provided", which showed a misunderstanding of what "provided" means.  Separately, if the real issue is with BouncyCastle jar hell, then the question should be rewritten so that someone who knows more about the various version of BC will be able to help.